# Column 'first_name' cannot be NULL VB.Net Error

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am creating a system. And now in stuck in the registration form that I am creating. I am using Visual Studio 2008 and using VB as my programming language connecting it to MySql Database using a MySql Connector 5.1.1.

I have these [structure of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpbFw.png) where it is Not Null but when I enter data in my registration form, I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BThnK.png)

And when I am changing it to Null in the structure of the table in the database, the data that I enter in the registration form that I created becomes Null in the database

I don't know if I have an error in my code or in my database. I am just a beginner, I hope someone will help me.

This is my code in my button to register a new user account in my registration form

```
    Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    Dim fname As String = txtboxfname.Text
    Dim lname As String = txtboxlname.Text
    Dim uname As String = txtboxuname.Text
    Dim pass As String = txtboxpass.Text
    Dim cpass As String = txtboxcpass.Text

    If txtboxfname.Text() = "" Or txtboxlname.Text() = "" Or txtboxuname.Text() = "" Or txtboxpass.Text() = "" Then

        MessageBox.Show("One Or More Fields Are Empty", "Missing Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)

    ElseIf Not String.Equals(pass, cpass) Then

        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Confirmation Password", "Password Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    ElseIf unameExist(uname) Then

        MessageBox.Show("This Username Already Exists, Choose Another One", "Duplicate Username", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    Else

        Dim conn As New DBCon()
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `login`(`first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (@fn, @ln, @usn, @pwd)", conn.getConnection())

        command.Parameters.Add("@fn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fname
        command.Parameters.Add("@ln", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lname
        command.Parameters.Add("@usn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = uname
        command.Parameters.Add("@pwd", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pass

        conn.openConnection()

        If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then

            MessageBox.Show("Registration Completed Successfully", "User Added", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            conn.closeConnection()

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("Something Happened", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            conn.closeConnection()

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And this is the code in my connection of VB to MySql

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class DBCon
Private conn As New 
MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=blood_elements")  

ReadOnly Property getConnection() As MySqlConnection
    Get
        Return conn
    End Get
End Property

Sub openConnection()

    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If

End Sub

Sub closeConnection()

    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        conn.Close()
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: i can't see an errro fname seems to be empty or NULL, so check it please

Answer (score 1):

There is one big problem with your system. Connections and some other database objects need to be not only closed but disposed. They use unmanaged code and when you call .Dispose they release resources in that unmanaged code. Create your connections in the method where they are used. Separate you data access code from your user interface code. After all, tomorrow management might decide they want a web app. You will be all ready to add your data access code to a different user interface.

Fortunately, vb.Net and C# provide Using blocks to close and dispose objects.

You should have very little code in the Event Subs. All the message boxes are shown in the user interface code, not in the data access code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not ValidateNewUserInput() Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim Success = DataAccess.InsertUser(txtboxfname.Text, txtboxlname.Text, txtboxuname.Text, txtboxpass.Text)
    If Success Then
        MessageBox.Show("Registration Completed Successfully", "User Added", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Something Happened", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub
```

In the validation code I used IsNullOrEmpty on a trimmed string. This should cover white space like a tab or spaces in the text box. I also used OrElse which is a short-circuit operator. The If statement will stop evaluation conditions as soon as it finds a True.

Because the UserNameExists is a shared method, it is not necessary to create an instance of the DataAccess class.

```
Private Function ValidateNewUserInput() As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtboxfname.Text.Trim) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtboxlname.Text.Trim OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtboxuname.Text.Trim OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtboxpass.Text.Trim) Then
            MessageBox.Show("One Or More Fields Are Empty", "Missing Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        Return False
    ElseIf txtboxpass.Text <> txtboxcpass Then
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Confirmation Password", "Password Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Return False
    ElseIf DataAccess.UserNameExists(txtboxuname.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("This Username Already Exists, Choose Another One", "Duplicate Username", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Your data access might look something like this...

```
Public Class DataAccess

    Private Shared ConStr As String = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=blood_elements"

    Public Shared Function InsertUser(FirstName As String, LastName As String, UserName As String, PWord As String) As Boolean
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
                command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `login`(`first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (@fn, @ln, @usn, @pwd)", conn)
            command.Parameters.Add("@fn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FirstName
            command.Parameters.Add("@ln", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LastName
            command.Parameters.Add("@usn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName
            command.Parameters.Add("@pwd", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PWord
            conn.Open()
            If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Shared Function UserNameExists(UName As String) As Boolean
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
                command As New MySqlCommand("Select `first_name` From `login` Where `username` = @UName", conn)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UName", UName)
            conn.Open()
            Using reader = command.ExecuteReader
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Hi! I have used your code but still the same problem. The structure of the table is Not Null, and when I enter data in my registration form I still get the error. I also changed the structure of the table into Null in the database and still when I enter data in the registration form becomes Null in the database.